# Is it possible to write a function which dynamically operates on a global variable given it's name as a string parameter to a function?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to pass a string which names a global variable to a function which in turn operates on that variable in the global context?

Sample function:

```
// the parameter str may be a global like:  `"localStorage"`, `"sessionStorage"`.
function (str, key, value){
  // the `converted_str` means the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`
  converted_str.setItem(key, value)
}
```

---

**EDIT-1**

How about other case, such as `this` or not window global variable？

Comment: `window[converted_str].setItem(key, value)` may work.

Comment: @DongNguyen How about other case, such as `this` or not window global variable？

Comment: Please add an explanation why you would need such a "thing"? This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me.

Comment: @sof-03: you have to determine what is the object that method belongs to. In the case of "this", you may need something like "bind" to specify the context.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by system variable you mean global variable (which it appears you do), then yes:

```
function (str, key, value){
  window[str].setItem(key, value)
}
```

In a browser, global variables are members of the global `window` object, and can be accessed dynamically through that object.

For non-globals:

If it is a member of the current `this` object, you can use:

```
something.method = function (str, key, value){
    this[str].setItem(key, value)
};
```

Alternately, if you just have some variables you want to access dynamically, just put them in your own object.

```
var obj = {
    'something': function() {}
};

var str = 'something';
obj[str]();
```

Comment: How about other case, such as this or not window global variable？

Comment: @sof-03 do you mean the case if the global object is not `window`? If you know what it could be called before hand you can do something like this `var _global = global || window || this` . That line first checks for the global variable `global` and then, if it's unavailable, checks for `window` and if that is unavailable, defaults to `this`. Then you can use `_global[str]` in your function

Comment: @ChiragRavindra That won't work, because if global is not defined it will throw a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @sof-03 So long as it is a property of some object, you can reference it dynamically. Browser globals are a member of `window`. If it's a member of the current object, it an be accessed by `this`. If you have your own variables you wan to access, just make them properties of your own object.